# How can I run elisp code automatically in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a debugging/monitoring system for a particular application.  I would like to allow monitoring/debugging from an emacs session, and have it run automatically.

Is there a way to have an emacs execute the following code without passing anything on the command line or forcing the user to run a command?  I don't want to put it into the emacs init file because I don't want to be running useless debug monitors when users are not running the application.

```
(defun filter-output (process output)
  (eval (read output)))

(defun doit ()
 (let ((myproc (start-process "my-process" "*My DebugMonitor*" "/tmp/myProcess.py")))
      (set-process-query-on-exit-flag myproc nil)
      (set-process-filter myproc 'filter-output)))
```

Comment: You can call `emacs --eval "(some code)"` to have it execute additional code at startup, if that's what you are looking for. You may also be interested in `emacsclient`, but it sounds like really an odd way to go about using Emacs. Typical Emacs user restarts it once a few months, if not less... so having users restart an editor in order for it to start communicating with some other program would seem strange. Since this seems to be some sort of interpreter, you may want to look into Pymacs code w/r to how it does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *automatically* you mean that it will be run once when an Emacs session is created, and you don't want it to be on the command line (e.g. part of a startup script that invokes an OS command), and you don't want it to be in the user's init file, then consider placing it in `default.el`  or `site-start.el`.  See the Emacs manual, node `Init File`.

If by *automatically* you mean that it should be run periodically or run when some event triggers it, then invoke it from a timer.  See the Elisp manual, node `Timers`.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you're asking, but it sounds like you want it to be executed by an external event. Try

```
emacsclient -e doit
```

But of course you will still have to put that code in the init file, so it knows what `doit` *is*.